# NetTopologySuite Distance is returning odd results in .net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0, nettopologysuite

In my .Net Core 3 API, I set a user location like this:

```
userDetails.Location = new Point(userDetails.latitude, userDetails.longitude)
{
   SRID = 4326
};
```

and when I try getting users in a given radius

```
double radiusMeters = userSettings.Radius;
var usersWithinRadius = Context.UserDetails.Where(ud => ud.Location.Distance(userDetails.Location) <= radiusMeters).ToList();
```

When I set the radius to 75000 meters, for example, with the user Location being (32.600248, 35.1225), it returns a point that's more than 90km distance (31.78562 , 35.115335)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this to work correctly? In every post I've ever seen, the distanceBetween would be <= a number in meters. This is never going to work. var distanceBetween = Convert.ToDouble(location.GeoLocation.Distance(crime.GeoLocation).ToString());

Answer (score 3):

> it returns a point that's more than 90km distance

Note the arguments you pass in are **lat & lon** whose units are degree. As a result, the value returned is not a length in **Meters**. As you might find, the distance between `(35.1225, 32.600248)` and `(35.115335,31.78562)` returned by `Distance()` method is `0.81465950900299355`. Basically , it equals:

```
Math.sqrt((35.1225 -35.115335)*(35.1225 -35.115335) + (32.600248 - 31.78562)*(32.600248 - 31.78562))
```

If the two points are **close enough**, you can treat its unit as **Arc Degree** roughly:

[image]

Assuming the earth is a **perfect sphere** and the [Earth Circumference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_circumference) is `40,075.017 km`.

According to [How Far Is One Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Arcs_of_circles):

[image: arc length]

we can **roughly** calculate the distance as below:

```
distance = Circumference * d /360 
    = 40,075.017 km * 0.81465950900299355 / 360 
    = 90.69km
```

Since the `Where()` condition `0.81465950900299355 < 75000` is `true`, you'll get a point that's more than 90km distance.

Note we're assuming the two points are close enough here. In order to calculate the accurate distance, we need transform the `(lon,lat)` Coordinate to a projection  Coordinate Systems before we invoke the `Distance()` method.

Quoted from [Spatial Data -EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial)

> This means that if you specify coordinates in terms of longitude and latitude, some client-evaluated values like distance, length, and area will be in degrees, not meters. For more meaningful values, you first need to project the coordinates to another coordinate system using a library like ProjNet4GeoAPI before calculating these values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but :"Since the Where() condition 0.81465950900299355 < 75000 is true. "

Yes, but then it would also return other, further distant points, and it doesn't. I had to make the radius higher to reach the points that 92, 93 KM far.

Comment: @ZionHai The above way is a rough way to estimate the distance roughly when the two points are close enough. It is not used to calculate the accurate distance. Please project the `(lon,lat)` Coordinate  to a Projection Coordinate System (PCS) before invoking the `.Distance()` method.