# How to make a circle type buffer around NetTopologySuite Point with radius in N meters?

Tags: c#, uwp, nettopologysuite

I have to draw a circle with N meters diameter around some geolocation.

I could able to generate coordinates for vertically oriented ellipse only.

C#

```
using NetTopologySuite;
//
const int SRID = 4326;
var fact = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), SRID);
var point = fact.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(lat, long));
var bufferParameters = new BufferParameters();
var poly = point.Buffer(0.0005, bufferParameters) as NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon;
    
var coords = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
foreach (var cItem in poly.Coordinates)
{
    coords.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = cItem.X, Longitude = cItem.Y });
}
```

Please help me to understand how to set the radius and make circle instead of an ellipse.

[image]

Comment: I think part of the problem is that your coordinates are in a different unit system than meters. I would suggest to use an SRID with UTM zone (which has its coordinate system in meters rather than degrees). Then reproject it into 4326. Otherwise, do a rough conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363982/nettopologysuite-distance-is-returning-odd-results-in-net-core-3

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you must have solved this but in case anyone else is searching for it, here's my solution.

In my case the radius was in nautical miles. (this can be easily converted to meters.)

```
public static void CreateCirlceAndCheckPoints()
{
    // Define the Precision Coordinate
    var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(4326); // WGS84

    // Circle center coordinate
    var circleCenterCoordinate = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate(7.5404, 53.4837); // long, lat
    var circleCenterPoint = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(circleCenterCoordinate);
    
    //Plot circle
    var circle = PlotCircle(circleCenterCoordinate.Y, circleCenterCoordinate.X, 20);        
}

public static Geometry PlotCircle(double centerLat, double centerLon, double radiusInNauticalMiles)
{
    // PLOTTING OF CIRCLE
    // Earth radius in nautical miles
    const double EarthRadiusNauticalMiles = 3440.065;

    // Convert nautical miles to radians
    double radiusInRadians = radiusInNauticalMiles / EarthRadiusNauticalMiles;

    // Calculate coordinates along the circumference of the circle
    var coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i += 10) // Adjust the interval as needed
    {
        double angle = i * Math.PI / 180.0;
        double latitude = centerLat + (radiusInRadians * Math.Sin(angle));
        double longitude = centerLon + (radiusInRadians * Math.Cos(angle) / Math.Cos(centerLat * Math.PI / 180.0));

        //Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {latitude}, Longitude: {longitude}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{longitude}, {latitude}");
        coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
    }
    
    
    // CREATE POLYGON
    var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(4326); // WGS84
    var circle = new Polygon(new LinearRing(coordinates.ToArray()), geometryFactory);

    return circle;

}
```